# Whether a absolutely continuous function is Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be absolutely continuous and has a continuous second derivative,then necessarily is Lebesgue measurable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As absolute continuity implies continuity, we see that $ f $ is continuous. Therefore, $ f $ must be Lebesgue-measurable.